# MacBook Pro doesnt boot after systemupdate / repairing volume doesnt work

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive, hardware, startup

i have a problem with my MacBook Pro.
I installed a Systemupdate, reboot and then i had a loading screen which loads a long time.

Then i started the mac in verbose mode and there is...

```
hfs: mounted Macintosh HD on device rootdevice
AppLeUS8MultitouchDriver::checkStatus - received Status Packets Payload 2: device was reinitialized
/devirdiskOs2 (NO WRITE)
Root file system
Executing fsck.hfs (version hfs-226.1.1).
/devirdiskOs2
Root file system
Executing fsck.hfs (version hfs-226.1.1)
[...] Checks
** Checking catalog file.
Incorrect number of thread records (4, 22547)
Incorrect number of thread records (4, 22547)
[...] More Checks
Repairing volume.
```

The Checks and Repairs start three/3 times.

After that the MacBook turns off without any information.

I startet the HDD Recovery program, but there is the same in the error log.

I dont know whats up with the Hard Drive -.-

Answer (score 1):

You can try boot your mac in recovery mode (hold command+R while booting), open Terminal, and running fsck to rebuild the btrees that hold the information of your files and directories structure.

To rebuild the catalog btree:

```
fsck -d -r /dev/disk0s2
```

Rebuild extents btree:

```
fsck -d -Re /dev/disk0s2
```

Rebuild attributes btree:

```
fsck -d -Ra /dev/disk0s2
```

Replace "disk0s2" by the id of the partition you want to fix. You can find out what's the id by running
    diskutil list

"-d" means show debugging information. This can be very useful to understand what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

While this could be an actual hardware error you may have run across an issue that Apple's Disk Utility can't actually repair. Unfortunate but little can be done about it with the built in tools.

If you have a full backup of any needed files you could boot into recovery mode, re-partition the drive and reformat, install the O/S and restore your files.

If that is not an option then I would go with one of the commercial disk repair tools. My favorite and go-to utility is DiskWarrior. If you have access to a Mac with an optical drive you can purchase online and download a disk image that you could burn to CD.

DiskWarrior has fixed any fixable disks I have thrown at it in the last ~10 years. I have also used Prosoft's Drive Genius and Micromat's TechTool Pro but I, personally, would start with DiskWarrior.

Comment: DiskWarrior said it doesnt work with MacBooks Pros which produced after 06/2012. I bought it in 11/2012.

Comment: Grrrr... Hate it when that happens, hopefully an update is coming soon. Sorry for the false lead.